# Implementing multiple images in Article structured-data type

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

For example, there is a news article with 3 images. The first one — main picture, the other two — photos from social network.

I want: 1) define the first picture as main image. This one search engines should use for rich results.
2) Define other 2 images as related to the news topic.

#1 All images goes to Article.image property.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Article headline</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/photo1x1.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/photo4x3.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/photo16x9.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/2.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/3.jpg"
       ],
      "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
      "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00"
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

#2 Only first image goes to Article.image property, other two — Article.hasPart.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Article headline</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/photo1x1.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/photo4x3.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/photo16x9.jpg"
       ],
      "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
      "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
      "hasPart": [
      {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://example.com/photos/2.jpg"
      },
       {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://example.com/photos/3.jpg"
      }
      ]
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which one is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Define other 2 images as related to the news topic.

Structured Data is highly dependent on the content of the linked web page. If we assume that your web page has the appropriate structure for three images, then, in this case, using the property **[about](https://schema.org/about)** or **[subjectOf](https://schema.org/subjectOf)** can help you. Embed a type that is most appropriate for the sub-subject. And for this type, set a separate image property. This can create rich results that present images for the subject of the entire article and images for sub-subjects of the same article. However, structured data depends on the details.